# BeautifulSoup: save each interation of loop's resulting HTML

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have written the following code to obtain the `html` of some pages, according to some `id` which I can input in a URL. I would like to then save each html as a  `.txt` file in a desired path. This is the code that I have written for that purpose:

```
import urllib3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import pandas as pd


def get_html(id):
    url = f'https://www.myurl&id={id}'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    html=print(soup)
    return html
 
id = ['11111','22222']

for id in id:
    path=f'D://MyPath//{id}.txt'
    a = open(path, 'w')
    a.write(get_html(id))
    a.close()
```

Although generating the `html` pages is quite simple. This loop is not working properly. I am getting the following message `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None`. Which means that the first loop somehow is failing to generate a string to be saved as a text file.

I would like to say that in the original data I have around 9k ids, so you can also let me know if instead of several `.txt` files you would recommend a big `csv` to store all the results. Thanks!

Comment: Try changing `for id in id` to `for orgid in id` and `path=f'D://MyPath//{id}.txt'` to `path=f'D://MyPath//{orgid}.txt'` (in addition to the answer about not using print)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the `print()` returns `None`. Use `str()` instead:

```py
def get_html(id):
    url = f'https://www.myurl&id={id}'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    #html=print(soup)  <-- print() returns None
    return str(soup)   # <--- convert soup to string
```

Comment: thanks! That makes sense. However now I get the error message: "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25b2' in position 72423: character maps to <undefined>"

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez Where you get the error? When you `.write()` the string? You might to set the correct encoding when opening the file: `open(path, 'w', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot :)